# Change inputs through Google Sheets Query

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query, gs-vlookup

I am using QUERY function in google sheets to select Province column (H) where  R,V,W are not zero. Province names are abreviations like ON, BC, AB, etc. The query below works fine:

```
QUERY(Data_Dump!A3:W,"SELECT H WHERE (R <> 0 OR V <> 0 OR W <> 0)",0)
```

However I want to also change the province names while transferring. For example changing "ON" to "Ontario" and "BC" to "British Columbia", etc.

I was thinking to combine `SWITCH` or `SUBSTITUTE` with my query similar to this:

```
=ArrayFormula(substitute(QUERY(Data_Dump!A3:W,"SELECT H WHERE (R <> 0 OR V <> 0 OR W <> 0)",0),"ON","ONTARIO"))
```

This certainly is wrong and only tries to change ON to Ontario. Just as an example of what I tried.

*** UPDATE:
[Here is a sample Google Sheet I share.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18rNWyigZ4ZBAec4OWnOB2FGvS9LaZ4lxlSf9ZhJA4OQ/edit?usp=sharing)

Appreciate any help here.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: Just did so, thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({IFNA(VLOOKUP(Data_Dump!H3:H, {
 "ON", "Ontario"; 
 "AB", "Alberta"; 
 "QC", "Quebec";
 "BC", "British Columbia";
 "NS", "Nova Scotia"}, 2, 0)), Data_Dump!B3:W},
 "select Col1,Col18  
  where Col18 <> 0 
     or Col22 <> 0 
     or Col23 <> 0", 0))
```

[image]

### [spreadsheet demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1N-1QI0IkSnr_kwIZU_OMlzQQvhVmcbldawiZGw3V72A/edit#gid=0)